# Euler 11. There must be a better way than this

Tags: java, matrix

I'm working on the project Euler problems, and I'm not really satisfied with my solution for problem 11. Is there a way that I can traverse the matrix with fewer steps, or more quickly? Or in general, is there a better way to solve it?

numbers.txt is the matrix of numbers given in problem 11.

http://projecteuler.net/problem=11

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int [][] matrix = new int [20][20];
        populateMatrix(matrix, "numbers.txt");
        System.out.println( greatestProduct(matrix) );
    }
    public static long greatestProduct(int [][] matrix){
        final int NUMBER = 4; 
        final int LIMIT = matrix.length - NUMBER;
        long max = 0;

        for(int i= 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j= 0; j <= LIMIT; j++){
                long diagTrack = 1, diagTrack2 = 1, horTrack = 1, horTrack2 = 1;
                int y = j;
                int x = i;
                int r = matrix.length-i-1;
                for(int index =0; index<NUMBER; index++){
                    if(i <= LIMIT){
                        diagTrack *= matrix[x][y];
                        diagTrack2*= matrix[r][y];
                        x++;
                        r--;
                    }
                    horTrack *= matrix[i][y];
                    horTrack2*= matrix[y][i];
                    y++;
                }
                if(max < diagTrack) max = diagTrack;
                if(max < diagTrack2) max = diagTrack2;
                if(max < horTrack) max= horTrack;
                if(max < horTrack2) max = horTrack2;
            }
        }
        return max;     
    }

    public static void populateMatrix(int [][] matrix, String fileName){
        File file = new File(fileName);

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            for(int i= 0; scanner.hasNextLine(); i++) {
                String line[] = ( (String) scanner.nextLine() ).split(" ");
                for(int j= 0; j < line.length; j++)
                    matrix[i][j]= Integer.parseInt(line[j].trim() );
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is @hakre when you need him? (LOL)

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [codereview.se]?

Comment: "Or in general, is there a better way to solve it?" Not really.

Comment: @Josh Horowitz did you try to read forum thread related to this problem?

Comment: Yes. Lots and lots of people talking about how they searched the matrix by hand and "looked for big numbers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trik i can think of is using fact that if you have 
 a,b,c,d,e,f  you can get all this values by

```
val1 = a*b*c*d
val2 = val1*e/a
val3 = val2*f/b
```

but since division is pretty expensive i think that this is even worse than 2 multiplications.
There might be some other uber tricks than will make code just more complicated. For instance.

```
If a>e than a*b*c*d > b*c*d*e
```

But that would be just complication overkill. Lets just assume that for some reason multiplication is very slow. This would be than acheived by memoisation and expressed.

```
a*b*c*d =  multiply(a,b)*multiply(c,d)
```

At the end I think that in reality is multiplication just as fast as storing and then reading from it if not faster, and that mean that your approach is just as good as anything else but most important is that it such naive solution can be easily implemented.